# weird /ws/info requests on our server: is our client compromised?

Tags: hacking, http-status-code-404

We have a big website on a virtual server that runs fine. We have a few hundred clients. Since a few weeks, we saw that with exactly ONE of these clients there were 404 references to hrefs like [www.example.com/ws/info?t=1508786142892](http://www.example.com/ws/info?t=1508786142892) . Every time with a different number. Of course, that url does not exist with us, but we get quite a few 404's in our logs. We wanted to make sure nobody is trying to hack us via her account.

We contacted her, she scanned her computer on viruses, the IP on which the requests were done was indeed hers and she confirmed she was on our website during the 404's. The weird thing is that there are only two or three very specific referer-URL's, and only with that user. I don't want to bother our client any further, since I had her check her browser plugins and IP address already and made her do a virus scan. The requests are made from het IP after being logged in.

What do you guys/gals think? Do you recognise the URL? Is it a rogue browser plugin? But why on only a few specific pages? And why only her and nobody else? I googled /ws/info, found something about WebSockets but I don't know anything about WebSockets. The url is nowhere to be found in our website or database. I also looked at all the js files that are included: no ws, no info, no /ws/info

The page is PHP with these js plugins: jQuery/jquery-ui/bootstrap/cookieconsent/googleSeach/googletagmanager/google analytics

Any ideas what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the numbers increasing or completely random? Maybe it's a UNIX timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, increasing, good catch.